# .load two different D3 tree layouts

Tags: jquery, html, d3.js, tree

I have two D3 tree layout diagrams, each into its own HTML page (with style and script). They are loaded into two different `div` through `.load()` JQuery method. 
In their own HTML pages they have the same variables names (i.e. node, links, nodeEnter, etc..).

If I load only one of them in the external HTML, it works perfectly. However, if I try to put them both in the page, they probably create some kind of conflict (it may be because of the same names of variables). 
I also tried to change variables names in one of the two HTML tree file, but with no result.

Is there another method to load the two tree pages without creating conflict?

Here's the original D3 example: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092

Comment: put it on JSFiddle. Are you using the same data for each tree ? If you are maybe you are altering the data in one tree, then cant read it in the second as you have changed it

Comment: put it on JSFiddle. Are you using the same data for each tree ? If you are maybe you are altering the data in one tree, then cant read it in the second as you have changed it